# How to disable scrolling the parent page when iframe expands ?

Tags: javascript, iframe, scroll

I am working on some sort of slider, which slides in when users clicks to expand. I have it working but i want to disable scrolling on the main page when i expand. I have used below code and played around with it but not got so far

```js
var $window = $(window), previousScrollTop = 0, scrollLock = false;

$window.scroll(function(event) {     
    if(scrollLock) {
        $window.scrollTop(previousScrollTop); 
    }

    previousScrollTop = $window.scrollTop();

});
```

any help or suggestion will be very useful. Im a beginner with JS

Thank You

Comment: Try to add this within your if condition : event.preventDefault();

Answer (score 0):

Just add a class to the body element of the page when the user expands your slider that sets overflow:hidden.

In CSS:

```
body.slider-open {
  overflow:  hidden;
}
```

In JS when your element opens or closes:

```
document.body.classList.toggle('slider-open);
```

Comment: Thanks man that didnt work for me , i added a function to detect mobile  function isMobile() {
    return (device.is_android() || device.is_blackberry() || device.is_ios() || device.is_windows_phone() );

 if(isMobile()){
document.body.style.overflow = 'hidden';
}
 }